# C# code generation with Google Protobuf proto2 files

Tags: c#, auto-generate, protocol-buffers, protobuf-csharp-port

I have several .proto files with proto2 syntax. I am trying to auto-generate C# classes using the protoc compiler but I get the error: "C# code generation only supports proto3 syntax.

Other than manually updating each .proto file to conform to proto3 syntax, is there no other way to auto generate C# classes? I'm completely new to protobuf so I know this may sound like a weird question given that the compiler clearly states that I have to follow proto3 syntax - I'm just wondering if there was ever a workaround to getting C# classes to work with proto2 syntax.

Comment: This [early alpha of 3.0.0](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.0.0-alpha-3) says it only supports proto2

Comment: Also https://github.com/jskeet/protobuf-csharp-port which the preceding link's C# support was built on

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ancient/venerable protogen.exe from the [protobuf-net 1.0.0.280](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/1.0.0.280) package to do the trick, or the slightly more modern, but still no longer maintained [protobuf-csharp-port](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.ProtocolBuffers/) project.